# Bottled a Belgian ale not carbonating

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning, belgian

I used white labs abbey ale yeast - fermentation went well and flocculated quite a bit. I then bottled straight from primary. I noticed that not a lot of yeast went into the bottles which hasn't really happened before (usually there's a visible layer or sediment. Also doesn't help that it's quiet dark brown in a brown bottle.

Anyway, the bottles have been sitting for about 10 days now, so I cracked one open to see how carbonation was going and nothing...completely flat. Tried another bottle same thing - bottles are near new and were sanitised so that's not the issue.

If only a small amount of yeast got in the bottles - should they still carbonate ok given more time or am I destined for a flat batch?

---

**Update:**
It is carbonating, just very slowly. They needed some rotation, a warmer room + time. 4 weeks and beer has low levels of carbonation

**Update 2:** Most bottles have carbonated at 7-8weeks. I noticed some do not have a fine yeast layer on the bottom so could have somehow not gotten much. Another thought for the overall slow carbonation, is that I didn't mix/turn the bottles an hour+ after bottling when the sugar had dissolved. Other than that, it may be but down to super malty beers?

Comment: Did you add priming sugar at bottling time?

Comment: yeah - sugar drops

Comment: I can't give an answer. What I do know from experience is that even after a couple of weeks in a fresh place (not cold), there is normally enough yeast to carbonate, let alone from bottling straight from primary. Did you put your bottles in a warm place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a high gravity beer right?  Just wait, it will get there.

Ensure they are stored somewhere good for ale temperatures (> 15C / 60F).
If you're really worried, give them a gentle shake every day for a few days.  Just enough to rouse the yeast.

Comment: Had pretty poor efficiency, so ended up about 6%. Yeah the room is about 15c. I think they do need a bit of a roll and another week.

Comment: I've had a high gravity Belgian ale take ~ 5 weeks to carbonate fully.  The yeast was hampered by the relatively high amount of alcohol I would suspect.

Answer (score 0):

The simple plan for bottle conditioning beer is to add sugar in some form to a bottle of beer, cap it and wait.  Is the temperature in the active range for the yeast?  I think you probably have plenty of yeast, I would roll the bottles a bit to insure a good mix and wait a bit longer in a good temperature environment.
The fuzzy science on adding more sugar at this point (usually in a simple syrup solution) is a crap shoot to get carbonation or bottle bombs.   Higher ABV beers will take longer to carb, not sure what your beer’s ABV.